# Conversion of Lambda expression to Method reference

Tags: java, method-reference

I was trying to convert a lambda expression into method reference, but I failed to do so.
can anybody help me with this?
The lambda expression takes 2 int parameters adds it and return the result.

public class Addition {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;

    A ref = (int c, int d) -> c + d;
    System.out.println(ref.add(a, b));

}
```

}

Comment: what is `A` in your code? or did you meant `IntBinaryOperator ref = (int c, int d) -> c + d;` and `...println(ref.applyAsInt(a, b));`

Comment: A is a Functional Interface having the method signature of add(int n1, int n2);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the signature of the method implemented by your lambda expression, you can replace it with:

```
A ref = Integer::sum;
```

Since that `sum` method accepts two `int` arguments and returns their `int` sum:

```
public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why did you use Integer there?

Comment: @AshishSingh in order to use a method reference, you need a method. And Integer class happens to have a `sum` method which matches your lambda expression (i.e. both can implement your function interface).

Comment: Ow!! So this is something builtin.. :) I wanted If we can modify the code I provided to method reference.
But what you posted was great and something new  for me. Thanks. :)

Comment: @AshishSingh In order to use a method reference with the code you provided, you'd have to create a static method that takes 2 int arguments and returns an int. Then you can reference it with `Addition::methodName`.